# Annotation error while trying to upload image using symfony 4.4

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, symfony-4.4

[image]I am using Symfony 4.4 and trying to upload an image. But while creating schemas I am getting an Annotation error.

**[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Image\Image" in property App\Entity\Student::$photo was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?**

## Attaching the code snippets below, please say what is the mistake I made.

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

```
/** 
      * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the photo.") 
      * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/png", "image/jpeg" }) 
   */
    private $photo;
```

=====================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to add `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;` to the top of the file.

According to the error message and the documentation for [NoBlank](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html), that line should fix your issue.